# How can I set up Trello desktop notifications?

Tags: trello, notifications, google-chrome

What do I have to set up in Trello in order to get pop-up notifications through Google Chrome?

There's a bug on the [Trello development board](https://trello.com/c/851lmShn) about strange desktop notification behavior, but I haven't seen any documentation or way to set these up in Google Chrome. Based on the comments on the card, there must be at least a few people who have gotten it to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a little bit hidden in the current UI.  Here's how you enable desktop notifications:

1. Go to a board
2. Scroll to the bottom of the "Activity" widget (lower right)
3. Click "Allow Notifications"

[image: Trello activity feed]

This setting is **per-browser** (so you'll need to re-enable it if you use a different computer), and only works in Chrome.

If you don't see that link, check the **Notifications** section of `chrome://settings/content` to see what your notifications settings are (they may be set to "Do not allow"), and `chrome://settings/contentExceptions#notifications` to see which sites you're currently allowing/preventing notifications on.

**Notes**

- You'll only get notifications when someone @mentions you in a comment (e.g. when they say "Hey <kbd>@Derek</kbd>, what do you think?")

Comment: Turns out I already had Trello cleared to show notifications, but I had been expecting to get popups for general activity, not just mentions.

Comment: Looks like this has moved to the Notifications menu (the bell in the upper-right corner). There’s an item called “Allow Desktop Notifications”.